# Trying to add CSS styles to a theme

Tags: theming, 8

This is the content of the .info.yml file.

```
name: Endymion
description: Drupal 8 starter theme
type: theme
core: 8.x

libraries:
    - endymion/global-css

regions:
  header: Header
  primary_menu: 'Primary menu'
  breadcrumb: Breadcrumb
  content: Content
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar first'
  footer_first: 'Footer first'
```

This is the content of the .libraries.yml file.

```
global-css:
    css:
        theme:
            css/css1.css: {}
```

I keep getting this error message:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

How do I fix this error?

Additional point:

Get the same error message whether I'm running locally or on a remote server (siteground)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you should use 2 spaces to indent your YAML. It seems you either use 4 spaces or a tab.

That is the case for the libraries files as well as the libraries key in info file.

Comment: Everything else does look basically fine except the indentation.

Comment: I would even think that the only problem is the indentation in .info.yml file - as that breaks the parser because it's different from the rest of the file. If you use 4 spaces consistently it *may* work. But I suggest that you do not and stick to the coding standard which says 2 spaces. *Hint:* PhpStorm can format the file automatically for you ;)

Comment: Thanks Tomas Fejfar. That worked fine. I'm new to YAML. In fact I'm new to all this. Trying to start a post-retirement career. Do you know anyone who wants to employ a 71 year old trainee Drupaler :-)

Comment: Nope :) But nowadays no one needs to know you're 71, you can be 18 yo blonde for all I know. That's the beauty of the internet! Best of luck and huge respect!

Comment: Thanks. I've successfully added CSS and jQuery to my theme.